# Stdclass object to array in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3, stdclass

I am getting the Output as below mentioned i need to convert these std class objects as array

**Output for Value**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [PRODUCT_CODE] => PRD000001
)
stdClass Object
(
    [PRODUCT_CODE] => PRD000003
)
```

**Required Output**

```
$data = array('PRD000001','PRD000003');
```

I have used the below code how can i achieve the required format

```
$this->db->select('PRODUCT_CODE');
$this->db->from('NT_PATIENT_MEDICINE_LOG');
$this->db->where_in('PATIENT_CODE',$patient_code);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach($result as $key => $value):
        $data = array();           

        $data[] = $value[$key]['PRODUCT_CODE'];
        echo "<pre>";print_r($data); 
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: use **get_object_vars($obj);**

Comment: result_array() already gives result in array

Comment: Yes result_array() give the out put as array but i need in this way array('1','2') so that i can use them in the codeigniter update query @pradeep